# Trouble constructing correct regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to construct a regular expression that will match each line of the below list.

```
6220    1   10  Because he's the hero Gotham deserves,
6220    9   10   
5181    5   7   in time, like tears in rain. Time to die.
6220    3   10  So we'll hunt him.
6220    5   10  Because he's not a hero.
5181    6   7    
5181    2   7   shoulder of Orion. I watched C-beams
5181    4   7   Gate. All those moments will be lost
6220    6   10  He's a silent guardian.
5181    3   7   glitter in the dark near the Tannhäuser
6220    7   10  A watchful protector.
5181    1   7   believe. Attack ships on fire off the
6220    0   10  We have to chase him.
5181    0   7   I've seen things you people wouldn't
6220    4   10  Because he can take it.
6220    2   10  but not the one it needs right now.
6220    8   10  A Dark Knight.
```

Everything is fine until a line has a blank "message", for example lines 2 and 6. Here's what the current regular expression looks like.

```
var regex = new Regex(
    @"(?<id>\d+)\s+(?<index>\d+)\s+(?<count>\d+)\s+(?<message>.+)?");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText("samples.txt")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["message"].Value);
}
```

The current regular expression will set the line below itself as the message if the original message group is blank. I've tried quite a few things, as well as making the message optional. How can I allow the regex to recognize the message as empty?

Comment: your whitespace is not optional: ˋ\s+ˋ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<id>\d+)\s+(?<index>\d+)\s+(?<count>\d+)\s(?<message>.+)?
```

make your `\s+` a `\s` so there is something left to match rather than eating it